# Remove [worst-practices] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Just saw the [worst-practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/worst-practices) tag show up on the front page.  It's clearly meta, can we get it removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing it's been removed, it shows up as [zero answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/worst-practices).

It will be removed completely within 24 hours.